# angular - passing queryParams to active route before navigating to another route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, query-string

I have a clarity datagrid where clicking on a row will open the item by routing from /organization/overview to /organization/:id;

For UX reasons I would like to store the last clicked id as a queryParam before I navigate.

e.g

1. user clicks item with id=1234
2. route gehts updated to /organization/overview?id=1234
3. Navigate to /organization/1234

The idea is that when the user clicks the browser back button, the last clicked item will be highlighted. I do know that this behaviour could be easily implemented otherwise but this approach is what I'm interested in.
Below is the the openOrganization Method I have so far.

```
openOrganization(organization){
    this.router.navigate([], {
        queryParams: { oid: organization.id },
        relativeTo: this.activatedRoute
    });
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/organizations', organization.id]);
}
```

It does not work because the 2nd navigate call seems to interrupt or cancel the first on, before its finished.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should subscribe to your Router and snapshot your current route when the navigation end.
for example:

```
lastUrl: string;
constructor(private _router: Router) {
  _router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(e => {
    this.lastUrl = e.url;
  });
}
```

And then, the lastUrl variable holds the route that you came from.

--- Edit
Same with params, if you have specific params on each url, you can instead of get the url of the last route, get any params that you pass through.

Comment: Thanks for the the quick reply!